# Issues with updating an inventory in Python Code

Tags: python-3.x, inventory

I'm working on a program for a final in a class and I'm having some troubles with updating the created inventory. I've been able to get it to the point where I can do everything else in the code, but when I go to run the update section, nothing updates. I'd be really grateful for any help with this. All of my code is included below

```
class Automobile:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, color, mileage=0):
        self._make = make
        self._model = model
        self._year = year
        self._color = color
        self._mileage = mileage

    @classmethod
    def make_vehicle(cls):
        make = input('Enter vehicle make: ')
        model = input('Enter vehicle model: ')
        while True:
            year = input('Enter vehicle year: ')
            try:
                year = int(year)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Year must be a number", file=sys.stderr)
        color = input('Enter vehicle color: ')

        while True:
            mileage = input('Enter vehicle mileage: ')
            try:
                mileage = int(mileage)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Mileage must be an integer", file=sys.stderr)

        return cls(make, model, year, color, mileage)

    def add_Vehicle(self):
        vehicle = Automobile.make_vehicle()
        self.vehicles.append(vehicle)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\t'.join(str(x) for x in [self._make, self._model, self._year, self._color, self._mileage])
    


class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vehicles = []

    def add_vehicle(self):
        vehicle = Automobile.make_vehicle()
        self.vehicles.append(vehicle)

    def viewInventory(self):
        print('\t'.join(['','Make', 'Model','Year', 'Color', 'Mileage']))
        for idx, vehicle in enumerate(self.vehicles) :
            print(idx + 1, end='\t')
            print(vehicle)


print("This is the Vehicle Inventory Program.")

inventory = Inventory()
while True:
    print ("""
    1.Add a Vehicle
    2.Delete a Vehicle
    3.View Inventory
    4.Update Inventory
    5.Export Inventory
    6.Quit
    """)

    ans=input("What would you like to do? ")
    if ans=="1":
        #add a vehicle
        inventory.add_vehicle()
    elif ans=='2':
        #delete a vehicle
        if len(inventory.vehicles) < 1:
            print('Sorry there are no vehicles currently in inventory')
            continue
        inventory.viewInventory()
        item = int(input('Please enter the number associated with the vehicle to be removed: '))
        if item - 1  > len(inventory.vehicles):
            print('This is an invalid number')
        else:
            inventory.vehicles.remove(inventory.vehicles[item - 1])
            print ()
            print('This vehicle has been removed')
    elif ans == '3':
        #list all the vehicles
        if len(inventory.vehicles) < 1:
            print('Sorry there are no vehicles currently in inventory')
            continue
        inventory.viewInventory()
    elif ans == '4':
        #edit vehicle
        if len(inventory.vehicles) < 1:
            print('Sorry there are no vehicles currently in inventory')
            continue
        inventory.viewInventory()
        item = int(input('Please enter the number associated with the vehicle to be updated: '))
        if item - 1  > len(inventory.vehicles):
            print('This is an invalid number')
        else:
            if Inventory().add_vehicle() == True :
                inventory.vehicles.remove(inventory.vehicles[item - 1])
                inventory.vehicles.insert(item - 1, Automobile)
                print('This vehicle has been updated')
    elif ans == '5':
        #export inventory to file
        if len(inventory.vehicles) < 1:
            print('Sorry there are no vehicles currently in inventory')
            continue
        f = open('vehicle_inventory.txt', 'w')
        f.write('\t'.join(['Make', 'Model','Year', 'Color', 'Mileage']))
        f.write('\n')
        for vechicle in inventory.vehicles:
            f.write('%s\n' %vechicle)
        f.close()
        print('The vehicle inventory has been exported to a file')
    elif ans == '6':
        #exit the loop
        print('Thank you for utilizing the Vehicle Inventory Program. Have a nice day.')
        break
    else:
        print('invalid')
```

Comment: `if Inventory().add_vehicle() == True :` this doesn't refer to the original `inventory` it's creating a new Inventory. In any case `add_vehicle()` doesn't return anything, so it's never going to equal True. (and `== True` is superfluous).

Comment: There are lots of ways this code could be improved. But I guess you'll find that out when you get a mark back. Alternatively post in CodeReview.

Comment: @blueteeth Please don't recommend Code Review for questions containing known-broken code: it is [not ready for review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the `if` condition is wrong and also you are inserting the class `Automobile`. What you need probably is `Automobile.make_vehicle()`. So, update the code,

```py
    elif ans == '4':
        #edit vehicle
        if len(inventory.vehicles) < 1:
            print('Sorry there are no vehicles currently in inventory')
            continue
        inventory.viewInventory()
        item = int(input('Please enter the number associated with the vehicle to be updated: '))
        if item - 1  > len(inventory.vehicles):
            print('This is an invalid number')
        else:
            inventory.vehicles.remove(inventory.vehicles[item - 1])
            inventory.vehicles.insert(item - 1, Automobile.make_vehicle())
            print('This vehicle has been updated')
```